# converter pixel para centímetro openGL

Tags: java, opengl

Preciso mudar um objeto para onde o mouse for clicado, estou tentando fazer com um ponto para iniciar. Eu já consegui capturar a posição do mouse porém vem em pixel e eu preciso desse valor em centímetro. Segue abaixo um trecho do código.

```
gl.glPointSize(5);
gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);        
gl.glColor3f(0f, 0f, 0f);   
    gl.glVertex2d(p1,p2);            
gl.glEnd();
```

Função que captura a posição do mouse em pixel

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {  
System.out.println("Evento do mouse");
switch (e.getButton()) {
    case MouseEvent.BUTTON1:              
       p1= e.getX();
       p2= e.getY();          
       break;   
}
```

}

Comment: Larissa, por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel analisar melhor o codigo.

Comment: Pixel em centímetros é relativo. Para isso você tem que saber a relação Pixel por Centímetros ou Pixels por Polegada. Por que você precisa da medida em centímetros?

Comment: eu acho essa dúvida muito vaga, muito difícil tentar ajudar com tão pouca informação.

Comment: ao clicar com o mouse em qualquer parte da janela o desenho (ou uma parte dele) deve ser redesenhado no ponto onde o mouse foi pressionado.